# Python3 RushHour solver using iterative deepening

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, puzzle

I'm trying to create a RushHour puzzle solver using iterative deepening depth-first search. Now when I execute the script it generates too much nodes and rapidly eats the whole memory (allocation speed around 20MB/s). I know my solution for storing states of the board is not perfect but it shouldn't eat so much memory. (The whole project can be found here  [here](https://j91321@bitbucket.org/j91321/rushhour.git) )

```
import map from node import Node


def all_moves(node):  # returns all valid moves for node
    state = node.state
    output = []
    for i in state.cars:
        car_id = i[0]
        y = i[1]
        x = i[2]
        for action in actions:
            movement = state.is_movable(action, y, x)
            if movement[1] != 0:
                movement.append(car_id)
                movement.append(action)
                output.append(movement)
    return output


def generate_all_child(node):  # creates every new state based on list of valid moves and makes it a child
    for move in all_moves(node):
        action = move[-1]
        car = move[0]
        car_id = move[-2]
        for step in range(1, move[1]+1):
            child_state = node.state.action(car_id, car, action, step)
            child_node = Node(child_state, node)
            node.add_child(child_node)


def dls(node, node_depth):
    if node_depth >= 0:
        generate_all_child(node)
        if node.state.is_solved():
            return node
        for child in node.children:
            dls(child, node_depth-1)


stack = [] actions = ["left", "right", "up", "down"]

mapa = map.Map() mapa.load("krizovatka.csv") mapa.display_matrix() mapa.load_cars() root = Node(mapa, None) stack.append(root)

depth = 5 for i in range(1, depth+1):
    print(i)
    final = dls(root, i)
    print(len(root.children))
```

Comment: I only quickly read through all of your code, but it seems like you build alot of lists. Do you need to be using lists every where, or can you try to use generators?

Comment: yeah I know I use lists too much. Haven't used generators before, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a bug in is_solved() (map.py). It returned 0 even if the final state occurred, so it never stopped searching. Now it works, although is very slow but that's a different problem.